# How to update service json or array value on click in angular2?

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-services

I want to update a service by click.

- service

  ```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable()
  export class ImageoptionsService {

  publicImageOption() {
      return {
        imgoptions: {
        thumbBox: '.thumbBox',
        spinner: '.spinner',
        imgSrc: './assets/background/one.jpg'
      }
    }
   }
  constructor() { }

  }
  ```

And in a component I am calling it which is working fine. Now I want to update it's 'imgoptions' value by clicking on an element.

- mycomonent.component.ts

  ```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { ImageoptionsService } from "../imageoptions.service";

  @Component({
      selector: 'app-bglist',
      templateUrl: './bglist.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./bglist.component.css']
  })

  export class mycomonent implements OnInit {
    public backgrounds = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
    constructor( private imageservice: ImageoptionsService) { }
    changebg(index) {
    }
   ngOnInit() {
   }

  }
  ```
- mycomonent.component.html

  ```
    <ul class="imagelist">
        <li class="bgimage" *ngFor="let background of backgrounds; let imgi = index" (click)="changebg(imgi)">
           <img src="./assets/background/{{background}}.jpg" alt="{{background}}" /> 
       </li>
    </ul>
  ```

From the above example, I want to change the 'imgoptions' value in service by calling 'changebg(index){}' this function.

Please let me know if there is any way to execute this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is attached below:

Step 1:

Add one setter method in ImageoptionsService service which would update your service data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class ImageoptionsService {

private data = {
       imgoptions: {
         thumbBox: '.thumbBox',
         spinner: '.spinner',
         imgSrc: './assets/background/one.jpg'
       }
}

publicImageOption() {
    return this.data;
}

updateData() {
  // put your logic to update this.data
} 

}
```

Step2:

Use this method over service instance when event callback gets invoked:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageoptionsService } from "../imageoptions.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-bglist',
    templateUrl: './bglist.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bglist.component.css']
})

export class mycomonent implements OnInit {
  public backgrounds = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
  constructor( private imageservice: ImageoptionsService) { }

  changebg(index) {
    // invoking updateData method to update service data
    this.imageservice.updateData();  
  }

ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Cheers!